# DocX.dll - Break page if there is not enough space on page

Tags: c#, novacode-docx

Im using docX.dll from: https://docx.codeplex.com/

I have template docx with tokens, and im replacing it with text, tables, images. Is it possible to get paragraph position on page ? I have tokens to breakpage before every title token. Now i want to know how much space left after my title token or in what position is my title token. Is it possible to get it ?

Comment: The only thing I know you can do is have a temporary file which has a `Paragraphs` and/or `Tables` with the 'keep with next' and 'keep lines together' properties on them and then grab and place them to new document.